# For-loop exits too early, need help as to why

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop

I've written a simple function that takes a vector *vec*, iterates through it, performing an operation whose result is stored in another vector *vecRes* of same size at same index, and returns *vecRes* upon completing the loop. Below is function code:

```
function [ vecRes ] = squareTerms( vec )
    vecSize = size(vec);
    vecRes = zeros(vecSize);
    for i = 1:vecSize
        vecRes(i) = vec(i)^2;
    end
end
```

Problem is that it seems to exit too early, after only one iteration in fact as the output appears as:

```
vecRes = 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

For input:

```
vec = 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

I can't figure out why it does so. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) and read the documentation for the functions you are using. Particularly the output(s) of [`size`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html)

Comment: What are the contents of `vecSize`? I'm betting it's not what you are expecting.

Comment: And what you're after is simply `vecRes = vec.^2`, no loop necessary.

Comment: use `numel` instead of `size` for this case.

Comment: Yea, the issue was just this, figured since it was a single row matrix it would treat it as an array almost. Oh well, accepted ben's answer as it was most informative, even though the other by user*someNo* was just as correct and is just what I wrote now. Thanks for tip on elementwise operation instead of for loop btw, didn't think of it. Waste of space my loop is ^^

Comment: Not to mention precious CPU time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Size returns 2 values, rows and columns. Probably you are a having a 1xN vector. So size returns [1 N] and your loop runs 1 time.

```
>>> size ([1 2 3])
> 
> ans =
> 
>      1     3
> 
>>> 1:size ([1 2 3])
> 
> ans =
> 
>      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed out the problem. My preferred solution in this sort of case is to use `numel`, i.e.

```
vecRes = zeros(size(vec));
for i = 1:numel(vec)
   vecRes(i) = vec(i) ^ 2;
end
```

Of course, in this case, vectorisation is better still:

```
vecRes = vec .^ 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
for i = 1:vecSize
```

with

```
for i = 1:vecSize(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

vecSize is an array of numbers, not just a single value. For example, if vec is a 1 by 8 vector, then size(vec) will return [1, 8].

Therefore, your for-loop-statement,

```
for i = 1:vecSize
```

, is actually equivalent to something like:

```
for i = 1:[1, 8]
```

This doesn't make much sense. There are a number of ways to fix the problem. You could write:

```
for i = 1:length(vec)
```

or

```
for i = 1:numel(vec) % "numel" stands for "number of elements"
```

If the vector is 1xn instead of nx1, you can write:

```
for i = 1:size(vec, 2)
```

Yet another alternative is:

```
for i = 1:max(vecSize)
```

However, the most sensible option is not to write the squareTerms function at all and simply write

```
vecRes = vec.^2;
```

Note the dot before the caret. vec^2 and vec **.** ^2 are not the same thing.

If you put a dot before an operator sign, the operation will be performed element-wise. For example,

```
C = A * B
```

performs matrix multiplication, but

```
C = A .* B
```

will cause the first element of A to by multiplied by the first element of B, and the result will be assigned to the first element of C. Then, the product of the second elements of A and B will be taken, and the result will be stuck in the second element of C, and so on.

```
vecRes = vec.^2;
```